# How do I work with Nested JSON that also contains invalid NULL strings?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I’m not exactly a newbie but I am very much still learning, so if you can please provide details. I’m working with an API output within a Databricks Python notebook. The contents of a field come back with an oddly nested JSON statement which I’m having difficulty handling. The contents can change, essentially this is getting me the available options that are usable with a certain question, so each row represents a question and the values in the column “Options” provide all the potential answer options and more that are available in the system.

So my thinking is as follows;

1. I need to handle the nulls, as these are placeholder outputs that aren’t used.
2. Unpivot the data frame so that the question repeats for all associated answer options.

```json
{
    "1": {
        "Display": "Strongly disagree"
    },
    "2": {
        "Display": "Disagree"
    },
    "3": {
        "Display": "Neither agree nor disagree"
    },
    "4": {
        "Display": "Agree"
    },
    "5": {
        "Display": "Strongly agree"
    },
    "6":null,"7":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":null,"11":null,"12":null,"13":null,"14":null,"15":null,"16":null,"17":null,"18":null,"19":null,"20":null,"21":null,"22":null,"23":null,"24":null,"25":null,"26":null,"27":null,"28":null,"29":null,"30":null,"31":null,"32":null,"33":null,"34":null,"35":null,"36":null,"37":null,"38":null,"39":null,"40":null,"41":null,"42":null,"43":null,"44":null,"45":null,"46":null,"47":null,"48":null,"49":null,"50":null,"51":null,"52":null,"53":null,"54":null,"55":null,"56":null,"57":null,"58":null,"59":null,"60":null,"61":null,"62":null,"63":null,"64":null,"65":null,"66":null,"67":null,"68":null,"69":null,"70":null,"71":null,"72":null,"73":null,"74":null,"75":null,"76":null,"77":null,"78":null,"79":null,"80":null,"81":null,"82":null,"83":null,"84":null,"85":null,"86":null,"87":null,"88":null,"89":null,"90":null,"91":null,"92":null,"93":null,"94":null,"95":null,"96":null,"97":null,"98":null,"99":null,"100":null,"101":null,"102":null,"103":null,"104":null,"105":null,"106":null,"107":null,"108":null,"109":null,"110":null,"111":null,"112":null,"113":null,"114":null,"115":null,"116":null,"117":null,"118":null,"119":null,"120":null,"121":null,"122":null,"123":null,"124":null,"125":null,"126":null,"127":null,"128":null,"129":null,"130":null,"131":null,"132":null,"133":null,"134":null,"135":null,"136":null,"137":null,"138":null,"139":null,"140":null,"141":null,"142":null,"143":null,"144":null,"145":null
}
```

Can you help me understand what I need to do here? Happy to provide better details/context if my question isn’t clear enough.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve in the second point (unpivoting)? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dropFieldIfAllNull` option to remove null fields when reading in the json file:

```
df = spark.read.json('option.json', dropFieldIfAllNull=True)

df.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------+----------+----------------------------+-------+----------------+
|1                  |2         |3                           |4      |5               |
+-------------------+----------+----------------------------+-------+----------------+
|[Strongly disagree]|[Disagree]|[Neither agree nor disagree]|[Agree]|[Strongly agree]|
+-------------------+----------+----------------------------+-------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I need to handle the nulls, as these are placeholder outputs that aren’t used.

To ignore nulls answer options use [`dropFieldIfAllNull`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json-java.lang.String...-) when you load the JSON into DataFrame using `spark.read.json`:

```
df = spark.read.json('/json/data', dropFieldIfAllNull=True)
```

> 2. Unpivot the data frame so that the question repeats for all associated answer options.

To get one row per `question | option_id | answer` you can use this :

```
# I guess you have a DataFrame like this after you drop all null options
df.show(truncate=False)

#+-------------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------+-------+----------------+
#|question     |1                  |2         |3                           |4      |5               |
#+-------------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------+-------+----------------+
#|Some question|[Strongly disagree]|[Disagree]|[Neither agree nor disagree]|[Agree]|[Strongly agree]|
#+-------------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------+-------+----------------+

# create a struct for each questions option which holds option ID and answer
answer_options = F.array(*[
    F.struct(
        F.lit(c).alias("option_id"), 
        F.col(c).alias("answer")
    ) for c in df.columns[1:]
])

df1 = df.select("question", F.explode(answer_options).alias("options")) \
        .select("question", "options.*")

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+-------------+---------+----------------------------+
#|question     |option_id|answer                      |
#+-------------+---------+----------------------------+
#|Some question|1        |[Strongly disagree]         |
#|Some question|2        |[Disagree]                  |
#|Some question|3        |[Neither agree nor disagree]|
#|Some question|4        |[Agree]                     |
#|Some question|5        |[Strongly agree]            |
#+-------------+---------+----------------------------+
```